# Android emulator gives error "Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed" and exits

Tags: android, android-emulator

After updating AS now emulator quits every time I start it. Below is the screenshot I managed to capture before it disappeared.
[image]

In the logs the following are printed

> 14:49 Emulator: WARNING: change of renderer detected.
>
> 14:49 Emulator: C:\Users\Nux\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
>
> 14:49 Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
>
> 14:49 Emulator: qemu: unsupported keyboard cmd=0x84
>
> 14:49 Emulator: qemu: unsupported keyboard cmd=0x84
>
> 14:49 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

I already tried the following:

1. Delete all my virtual devices and created new ones.
2. Wipe Emulator data.
3. Tried to lunch emulator manually in AVD.
4. Launch emulator with the option "Cold boot now".

And none of them worked. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @Sampgun I have not fixed it yet!

Comment: Ok I have something...I deleted everything and simply downloaded the Android Studio executable. Run everything and now it works.

Comment: Anyway sometimes it fails to run with the same error.

Comment: @Sampgun I did the same thing. Uninstalled everything and  Downloaded new AS. but It the error still persists. got tired and I use my phone right now

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same. I was excited to see they switched to IntelliJ IDEA as base IDE (I hate Eclipse from the deep), but everything works more or less as it did when I tried last time (Ice Cream was the latest at that time)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. What worked for me:

1. Editing the AVD configuration and on Graphics I selected "Software".
2. Lower uncheck "Device Frame".(without this step it was keeping crashing).
3. Wipe data
4. Cold boot.

And now it works fine. Hope my advice will help to anyone.

Comment: does not work ( Windows7, Android Studio 3.4, Android 9 Emulator Only)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Xamarin and VS2019. I installed an Android API 29 emulator and the emulator was quitting without any error messages. The device manager log showed "Error: WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value" and "only 'qemu.*' properties are supported". I'm not sure how symptomatic those messages are. However, my Emulator Accelerator was at version 6.something. Updating to latest fixed the problem. In my case this was 7.6.5. In VS2019 its Tools > Android > Android SDK and Tools > Tools > Extras.

Comment: I'm using VS2022 Preview and I had the same problem, but I wasn't find how to configure these settings. I think when I installed VS2022, just Android SDK was installed, so I had to install Android Studio, and then I could change the settings like @Arun suggested. Now the emulator is working fine.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem.
If riot games are installed on your computer, stop Riot Vanguard and try again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpX1I.png)

Comment: Omg, this actually fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101060131/https://www.programmersought.com/article/25974077755/) which allowed me to fix the problem. Follow these steps:

1. In Tools > SDK Manager, make sure HAXM is installed and up-to-date. You can also manually install it from Github and restart Android Studio.
   [image]
2. Open environment variables and add a new variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`, set the value to `C:\Users\<yourUserNameHere>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
   [image]
3. Go to `C:\Users\<yourUserNameHere>\.android` and copy the **avd** folder to `C:\Users\<yourUserNameHere>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
   [image]
4. Now open Android Studio and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem and fixed by:

Start - Turn windows features on or off - (checking) Hyper-V - Reboot

Hyper-V "lets you create and run a software version of a computer, called a virtual machine. Each virtual machine acts like a complete computer, running an operating system and programs." - Microsoft docs

NB I also installed android emulator components like HAXM for Visual Studio 2022 Community, but this didn't fix problem on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue when updating Android Studio to version 3.4.

What worked for me was editing the AVD configuration and on Graphics I selected "Software -GLES 1.0". This made my emulator successfully boot up again.

Then I just went back to the Graphics configuration and selected "Hardware - GLES 2.0" again, which made my emulator go back to its usual performance.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I installed on my MacBook Pro 16inch and had the same problem, this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

if your using visual studio to run your emulator .
1-restart your pc.
2-run your emulator from android studio first.
this solved my problem.

Comment: It worked for me, the issue was "HAXM" was not correctly installed and while installing android studio it showed up the error and need to enable "secure boot" option from the BIOS due to which I am able to install "HAXM" correctly and which in tern solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since it gave me an error in the error list, I knew what to install. So I opened up command prompt and typed in:

> dotnet workload install wasm-tools-net6

And it's now downloading the required tools to run the Android emulator. (wasm-tools-net6 was included in the error message - yours may differ).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33869464)

Answer (score 0):

In the Android virtual Manager -> Actions -> arrow down -> Cold Boot Now. And ready.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this problem.

I updated my windows 10 1904 to 2004, this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows10. Update your windows 10 1904 to 2004, this way I solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create an emulator for `Android 10` (the one for `Android 9.0` worked fine) but I also got the error:

```
Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed
```

After some digging on the World Wide Web I found that I did not have the `Android SDK 10.0 (Q)` installed.

Steps (from `Android Studio`):

**Step 1**: Open `SDK Manager` (`Tools` -> `SDK Manager`)

**Step 2**: Choose your missing Android SDK and  click `Apply`
[image]

**Step 3**: Wipe the data from existing virtual device (`Tools` -> `AVD Manager` -> Right-click on virtual device -> `Wipe Data`)

After the installation I right-clicked on my already existing virtual device and choose `Wipe Data`. I'm not sure it this is necessary though. Note that the same error - `Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed` - appeared but then it booted up correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was creating an emulator for Android API 30 and nothing of the above worked for me.

What solved my issue is:

- ensuring the x86_x64 processor is selected when creating the new emulator
- make sure that Hyper-V is running on your machine (type Windows features in the search bar and scroll down to Hyper-V)

Restart your machine and the emulator will hopefully work :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost every solutions given by google. Since it was my first time installing Android Studio and got an error upon installing it, really frustrate me. The solution that works from me is this:

- Ensure the x86_x64 processor is selected when creating the new emulator
- make sure that Hyper-V is running on your machine (type Windows features in the search bar and scroll down to Hyper-V)
- Restart your machine and the emulator will hopefully work :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10

- Start - Turn windows features on or off
- Enable Virtual Machine Platform

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing VS for the first time, check hyper V is checked in add or remove windows features.