# Failed to create Vulkan instance - Android Studio, Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, vulkan

I need to work with Android studio, but Android virtual device is not starting.

I am getting this error:

```
22.04.2020
10:23   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.

10:23   Emulator: C:\Users\blatsabidze\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

10:23   Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

10:23   Emulator: Screenshot failed to find cb 0

10:23   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have hp prodesk 400 g3 mt with Intel HD Graphics 530, I5 6500

I there problem with my hardware?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, that's hard to tell where the problem is. Just a stupid question: The emulator supports graphics acceleration, right? I.e. can you install and run games from the play store? If so, have you tried running existing Android Vulkan example applications? [Sascha Willems' Vulkan Examples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan) should run on Android (haven't tried, though). I can confirm that running Vulkan on an Intel HD 530 is no problem at all, so the problem must be either with your application or with the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing HAXM solved my problem.

https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases

Answer (score 0):

I recently changed my `AVD Configuration > Graphics` to "Software" (because of what's suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319451/11240362)). When I set it back to "Automatic", the error was gone.