# Virtual Device in Android Studio doesnt work

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to run my project in Android Studio with my virtual device. When I run the project the phone appears with an error message, but I can't turn the virtual device on / use it.
The error:

[image: The error]

Why isnt it working, I dont understand the error message.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question: [Android emulator gives error "Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed" and exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090178/android-emulator-gives-error-resetting-for-cold-boot-emulation-engine-failed)

Comment: add your os info along with complete error message. To get the error message from emulator, open command prompt on windows and then `cd <android_sdk_folder>/emulator` . Next do `emulator.exe -list-avds` to get the emulator names. now do `emulator.exe @<emulator_name>` for the given emulator. If it shows any error then add it to your post.