# "Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed" in android studio with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio

I am trying to open my device in android studio and it gives me the following error when initializing it:

"Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed"

I tried to initialize it with the kernel logs and factory reset, and the error log gives me the following:

```
[2023-07-12 09:26:01.1]
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_33'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
[2023-07-12 09:26:01.1]
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=83228066-4f30-4302-9951-dc9ed7ff0b1c'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
[2023-07-12 09:26:01.2]
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
[2023-07-12 09:26:01.3]
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
[2023-07-12 09:26:02.2]
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
[2023-07-12 09:26:02.2]
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
[2023-07-12 09:26:02.2]
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
[2023-07-12 09:26:02.3]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
[2023-07-12 09:26:03.8]
```

I've already been looking for solutions but none worked for me.

Some links that I already visited:

> [Android emulator gives error "Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed" and exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090178/android-emulator-gives-error-resetting-for-cold-boot-emulation-engine-failed)
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-delete-avd-avdmanager-has-returned-non-z/1562079

I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance.